# How to disable/hide JxBrowser License information

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I am evaluating JxBrowser API for Java. I realized that the console will print out the license information during run project. Below is the information printed out during java program execution.

```
-- Product name: JxBrowser
-- Licensed version: 6.x
-- Licensed to: 
-- License type: Evaluation
-- Generation date: Jun 21, 2017
-- Expiration date: Jul 21, 2017
-- License info: Single-user license
-- Current date: Jul 3, 2017
JxBrowser license valid.
```

Is that possible to disable the printing of license information if I will purchase the license in the future?

I tried using:

```
System.setProperty("teamdev.license.info", "false");
Browser browser = new Browser();
```

but the console will still print the license information.

Comment: What happens if you don't add the `System.setProperty()` line at all?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts same behavior happened. Still print out the license information

Comment: yeah, i think i faced the same issue here. @j.ezekiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of using 30-days evaluation license the license information will be always printed into console output. It's true only for the evaluation license.

The license information won't be printed in case of using commercial license. So, when you purchase and use a commercial license, the issue will be solved automatically.